# php add multiple to cart method

Tags: php

I am currently able to add a quantity of a product by one or reduce it by one within my cart however I'm trying to add a method whereby I can submit a quantity that I input into a text field.

To increase by one, this is the main part of the code. It is found on the index page.

```
        echo '<a href="cart.php?increase1='.$uniquenum.'"> Plus 1</a>';
```

This is the code on the cart page to get that uniquenum and action:

```
       if (isset($_GET['increase1'])) {
         $result = 'cart_' . $_GET['increase1'];
         $_SESSION[$result] = isset($_SESSION[$result]) ? $_SESSION[$result] + 1 : 0;
       }
```

How could I get the $uniquenum variable from the index page to the cart page using a form and post or get request. If I could do this I could update a quantity. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of GET you should use POST method.    
Otherwise first search crawler to find your shop will be first one to buy all your stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you put all code belonging to the logic of the cart into a class of it's own. You can then use it as a facade in your code:

```
// initialize session for Cart
$_SESSION['cart'] || $_SESSION['cart'] = new Cart();

// fetch cart from session
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
```

Then provide methods by cart that offer the functionality you're looking for, either in a simplified form:

```
$cart->increadeByOne($item);
```

Or by giving full access to encapsulation of a more differentiated level:

```
$cart->getItem($item)->getQuantity()->increaseBy($number);
```

The last example might seem to be bloated, but generally it's good to have a base `Cart` class so you can better handle and test your operations.

You can then bind that with your GET request:

```
if (isset($_GET['increase1']))
{
    $cart->getItem($_GET['increase1'])->getQuantity->increaseByOne();
}
```

Some rough Cart and Quantity layout:

```
Class CartItemQuantity
{
     private $item;
     private $quantity = 0;

     public function __construct(CartItem $item)
     {
         $this->item = $item;
     }

     public function increaseByOne()
     {
         $this->increaseBy(1);
     }
     public function decreaseByOne()
     {
         $this->quantity = max(0, $this->quantity - 1);
     }
     public function increaseBy($number)
     {
         $this->quantity = max(0, $this->quantity + $number);
     }
     public function getQuantity()
     {
         return $this->quantity;
     }
     public function setQuantity($quantity)
     {
         if (is_string($quantity) && ctype_digit($quantity))
         {
             $quantity = (int) $quantity;
         }

         if (!is_int($quantity))
         {
             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Not a valid quantity (%s).', $quantity);
         }

         $this->quantity = max(0, $quantity);
     }
}

Class CartItem
{
     private $quantity;

     ...

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->quantity = new CartItemQuantity($this);
         ...
     }

     public function getQuantity()
     {
         return $this->quantity;
     }
}

Class CartItems
{
     ...

     /**
      * @return CartItem
      */
     public function getItem($item)
     {
         ...

         return $item;
     }
}

Class Cart
{
     /**
      * @var CartItems
      */
     private $items;
     ...
     public function increaseByOne($item)
     {
         $this->items->getItem($item)->getQuantity()->increaseByOne();
     }

     /**
      * @return CartItem
      */
     public function getItem($item)
     {
         return $this->items->getItem($item);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// next line breaks for formatting only, take them out
echo '<form action="cart.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="increasewhat" value="'.$uniquenum.'">
    <label for="increaseby">Increase by</label>
    <input type="text" name="increaseby" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="increaseyes" value="Yes!">
    </form>';

//real linebreaks from here, parameters assumed to be validated
$result = 'cart_' . $_GET['increasewhat'];
$_SESSION[$result] = (isset($_SESSION[$result]) ? $_SESSION[$result]:0)+$_GET['increaseby'];
```

Comment: echo your SQL statement and post it

Comment: I'd rather not post too much code on here. Do you have msn or could I email you??

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="add_to_cart" method="get" action="cart.php">
   <label for="uniquenum">Quantity: </label>
   <input type="text" name="uniquenum" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

On the server side:

```
if (isset($_GET['uniquenum'])) {
  $uniquenum = $_GET['uniquenum'];
  /* Important! Check if it is an integer */
  if(is_int($uniquenum)) {
     $_SESSION[$result] = isset($_SESSION[$result]) ? $_SESSION[$result] + $uniquenum : 0;
   } else {
      echo "Invalid input!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action='cart.php' method='GET'>
Input quantity:<br/>
<input type='text' name='increase1'><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Increase'/>
</form>
```